# Pdf of a weighted sum of other pdfs

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image: This is from Stirzaker's Random Processes Textbook]

I do not follow the line of thought expressed above. How does the "taking of value X with probability a and Y otherwise" follow from a simple summation of random variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be esier to understand this way of thinking (discrete case),

Suppose we have this kind of game, first, you cast an unfair coin with $\alpha$ as the probability for head, and $1-\alpha$ for tail. If you get head, you take a ball from a bowl randomly which consists of 2 red balls and 3 blue ones. Other wise, you take a ball randomly from another bowl which consists of 4 reds and 1 blue. Hence, the probability you get blue is $\alpha\frac{3}{5}+(1-\alpha)\frac{1}{5}$

I hope it is clear enough. And for continuous case (your problem) is just the generalization of it.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it that in order to draw a random value from $Z$, we first draw a value $x$ from an unform $[0,1]$ distribution, and if $x < \alpha$ we take $X$, otherwise we take $Y$. The probability for choosing $X$ is $P(x<\alpha) = P(x \in [0,\alpha]) = \alpha$, the probability for choosing $Y$ is $P(x > \alpha ) = P(x \in [\alpha,1]) = 1-\alpha$.

I hope that cleared up the confusion. The function $h(x) :=  \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) g(x)$ actually *is* a probability distribution function because

$$\int_{\mathbb R} h(x) dx = \alpha \int_{\mathbb R}f(x)dx + (1-\alpha) \int_{\mathbb R} g(x)dx = 1\alpha + 1(1-\alpha) = 1$$ e.t.c.